# Weighted Median Filtering

Tags: algorithms, computational-complexity, signal-analysis

Let's begin with a little review of *unweighted* median filtering.

Suppose I have a list of $N$ real-valued numbers, $x=x_1,...,x_N$.  Let $m_i$ be the median of $K$ consecutive values: $m_i=$ median$(x_i,...,x_{i+K})$.  Let $m=(m_1,...,m_{N-K+1})$.  The act of transforming $x$ to $m$ is called (unweighted) [*median filtering*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median_filter).  We usually imagine $N\gg K$, and frequently we assume that $K$ is odd (so the median is unambiguously defined).

Median filtering is a useful smoothing technique in signal processing because it is robust against outliers; apparently the 2 dimensional analogue is useful in image processing because it smooths images while keeping edges relatively intact.

There is a naive $O(NK\log(K))$ algorithm to compute $m$ from $x$ (take each of the $O(N)$ windows $(x_i,...,x_{i+K})$, sort in $O(K\log(K))$ time, and report the medians).  However, this performance can be substantially improved (both in theory and practice).  The true complexity is $\Omega(N\log(K))$; see [[Suomela, 2014]](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1406.1717.pdf) for an overview of algorithms that can achieve this (plus a clever, new algorithm).

I am interested in a closely (?) related problem, *weighted* median filtering.  Given a set of $K$ weights, $w_1,...,w_K$, such that $\sum_i w_i=1$, and $w_i\geq 0$, the [weighted median](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weighted_median) of a set $z_1,...,z_K$ is the $z_i$ such that
$$\sum_{j: z_j<z_i}w_j<1/2$$ and
$$\sum_{j: z_j\geq z_i}w_j\leq 1/2$$

Note that if all the $w_i=1/K$, then the weighted median reduces to the regular median.

The naive algorithm (where we treat each window of length $K$ separately) can compute the weighted median in $O(NK\log(K))$.  As Emil points out, it is possible to compute the weighted median of a single set in $O(K)$ time (as outlined on the wikipedia page on weighted median), so one can improve this to $O(NK)$.  My question is: **Is there a more efficient algorithm?**

A few notes:

- If you assume that the $x_i$ take values over some small set, there
  are various special algorithms one can use.  Unfortunately for me, my
  values will probably be largely distinct.
- There is a paper by Zhang et al in 2014 with the promising title "[100+ Times Faster Weighted Median Filter](http://www.cse.cuhk.edu.hk/~leojia/projects/fastwmedian/download/fastweightedmedian_cvpr14.pdf)".  If I'm reading their paper correctly, the results only apply to the 2 dimensional problem, and (in the language of this post) reduces the complexity from $O(NK)$ to $O(N\sqrt{K})$ (although it's not clear to me if this result holds in one dimension).
- In typical usage, the weights form a [window function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Window_function) of some sort, which typically has a largest weight in the middle of the window, and then shrinks towards either end.  I would be very interest in a solution even if it only applied to this special case.

Comment: The Wikipedia page you link to tells me that weighted median can be computed in linear time, so the naive algorithm should be actually only $O(NK)$, right?

Comment: Good point; I'll update the post.